# Exception handling in Python

Tags: python, exception

http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html states that:

> `exception IMAP4.error`
>      Exception raised on any errors. The reason for the exception is passed to the constructor as a string.

What does "exception is passed to the constructor as a string" mean?  What would the code look like that can print the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the reason when constructing the exception yourself, and put it into a variable when catching the exception.

```
try:
    raise imaplib.IMAP4.error('Some exception')
except imaplib.IMAP4.error, error:
    print error
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `print str(exception)`.